# Different implementation of __import__() in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In Python 3 I got something like this to work:

```
def aFunctionImportingAndCallingAnotherFunction(functionName, args):
    packageString = "a_nested_package.to_be_imported.at_run_time"
    _temp = __import__(packageString, globals(), locals(), [functionName], 0)
    function = eval("_temp." + functionName)
    return function(args)
```

in Python 2.7 I get an error that the function I am passing in with `functionName` does not exist.

In this example the package `a_nested_package` is in `sys.path`, it has a package `to_be_imported`, which has a package `at_run_time`. All packages have `__init__.py` files.

I tried:

- playing with the level argument (I tried -1 and 1)
- removing `a_nested_package` from `packageString`
- removing `a_nested_package` from `packageString` and replacing it with `.`

Also, if this is completely the wrong approach to do run-time imports of functions, please let me know! I am pretty new to Python (coming from C++, PHP and Java)

Comment: Why are you not using the [`importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) instead?

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? import a module dynamically, or just pick an object *inside* the imported module dynamically?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: because I didn't know about it;-) I'll give that a quick try.

Comment: In other words, what is the dynamic part here, the module name, or the function name?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am importing a package that is only known at runtime (I know, this sounds awful, but I am trying to write a way for people to write plugins for my application.) Then from that package I am calling a known function with known arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) to dynamically import modules, then use `getattr()` to retrieve a specific name from that module:

```
import importlib

def aFunctionImportingAndCallingAnotherFunction(functionName, args):
    module = importlib.import_module(packageString)
    func = getattr(module, functionname)
    return func(*args)
```

Comment: @DudeOnRock: ah, no, disregard that remark, that's an explanation for things working the other way around. I just tested this on Python 2.7 and 3.3 and it works fine for me on both.

Comment: That is good to know, that might mean that somehow my `sys.path` is not the same in both versions. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

`__import__` works just like the `import` statement.  (For good reason.)

When you do this:

```
import foo.bar.baz
```

You don't get a `baz` object in your file; you get `foo`!  Likewise, this:

```
__import__('foo.bar.baz')
```

returns the `foo` module, but guarantees that it's been populated with `bar`.

So in your example, `__import__` is returning `a_nested_package`, and you have to traverse the rest of the path yourself.  Which sucks, and is why `importlib` is useful.  :)

Comment: But this is the same in both python 2.7 and 3.x, or am I mistaken?

Comment: it's the same.  the only difference is that `level` defaults to -1 in 2.7 and thus tries relative imports, which 3.3+ doesn't support.  compare the docs yourself: [2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), [3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)